# PHP Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in

Tags: php, magento

I recently transferred my magento website from an old server to a new one, and when I opened the home page, it gives me Internal Server Error 500. In the server error log, i can see the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /home/evonengc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you've not got the Intl extension enabled...

Answer (score 2):

go to php.ini and enable the extension

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

and restart Apache